# ssh connection refused Ubuntu 18.04 - Proxmox and OVH -

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, proxmox, ovh

I can connect to my server from my computer by ssh. I have internet connection. Everything works perfectly, but I can't connect to my server by ssh.

please check the screenshot for more information.

[ip a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYpxs.png)

[systemsctl status ssh.service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtI3u.png)

Comment: Can you paste here the command you are using and the result of it?

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly says that your server is configured to listen on port 1337 instead of standard 22.

You should specify the port on your client side:

`ssh 94.23.154.44 -p 1337`

OR edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and restart sshd service.

I checked the port and it's listening fine:

```
 telnet 94.23.154.44 1337
Trying 94.23.154.44...
Connected to 94.23.154.44.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
```